# Sort delimited data in a column, by criteria within each cell instead of by the leading character

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

The data are in a single column. Each cell in the column contains two fields, Name and Gender, delimited with a period:

```
    Juma. Male
    Ashura. Female
    Asha. Female
    Zachariah. Male
    John. Male
    Zainabu. Female
```

I want to sort the data by Gender, the second field in each cell. I know how to sort only by the first characters in each cell. I would like to list my students so that all females are listed alphabetically, followed by the males listed alphabetically:

```
Asha    Female
Ashura  Female
Zainabu Female
John    Male
Juma    Male
Zachariah   Male
```

Comment: Please share the expected result and the formula(s) or code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data are in a worksheet in column A, create 2 helper columns B and C:

[image: Data with helper columns]

```
B2:  =TRIM(LEFT(A2, FIND(".", A2) - 1))
C2:  =TRIM(MID(A2, FIND(".", A2) + 1, LEN(A2)))
```

(Use TRIM() to eliminate the extra spaces.)
Then sort all three columns by columns C, B:

[image: Sort with 2 criteria]